# What is the best way to compress a gif for the web without losing quality?

Tags: html, performance, web, compression, gif

I want to add a gif of an app that I'm working on to the app's [website](https://trymito.io/). Previously, I used quicktime to screen record my computer and then used [EZGIF](https://ezgif.com/) to convert the video into a gif. Unfortunetly, in order to get the gif to a reasonable size to embed on my website (~5MB), the quality goes completely down the drain (you can see the bad quality gif on the [website](https://trymito.io/) now.

To show off enough functionality of the app to make it worth going on the hompepage, the original video that I'm recording is ~45 seconds.

Are there other, better methods for recording / compressing gifs for websites?

Comment: This would be super helpful!

Comment: I'd try a different format, say WebM or MP4.